# How to use _embed when using _fields?

Tags: rest-api

It seems that if you use `_fields` in an API request also containing `_embed`, the `_fields` filter will filter out all embeds.

The following request:

```
domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=link,title&_embed=wp:featuredmedia
```

has no `_embedded` field, but it comes back if I remove the `_fields` filter. I also tried passing `_fields=link,title,_embedded`, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not clear in the documentation, but you need to include the "_links" and "_embedded" as fields to be returned.  In addition, I include the _embed parameter, as it [does not require a value](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/#embed). As of WordPress 5.4, the resources to embed can be limited by passing a list of link relation names to the _embed parameter, though I have not had success with that when using _fields

Example:

```
domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=link,title,featured_media,_links,_embedded&_embed
```

Comment: You're right! Adding `_links` made it work. I don't even have to include `_embedded`, for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Adding _links worked for me as well.

Comment: This works great indeed but now I get all the links content. Can that somehow be filtered out as it's a lot of KB's that I don't need being send.

Answer (score 0):

If you use somebody's REST API and you don't have access to WP website that provides this REST API you should use **dfmjr**'s solution. But this solution has 2 disadvantages:

1. You have to add additional parameters into every single request
2. You have to mention all the parameters that you need to be returned, otherwise they won't be returned.

But what if you have your own REST API and you want to return embedded media in your REST API responses every time and don't want to type all the fields you need in your request? Usually I have have such issue when I add a Custom Post Type in `functions.php` of my theme using `register_post_type()` function. In this case you should pass the `'_links'` value of the `'supports'` array to your `register_post_type()`. For example:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_types' );

function create_post_types() {
  register_post_type( 'book',
  array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => __( 'Books' ),
      'singular_name' => __( 'Book' )
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'rest_base' => 'books',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'book'),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', '_links')   // <--- INSERT '_links' HERE
  )
);
?>
```

And you won't need to add additional parameters into your REST API requests anymore:

```
domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `_link` is necessary, this is what you can do.

```
/wp/v2/pages?_embed&_fields=_links.wp:featuredmedia,_embedded.wp:featuredmedia
```

Or

```
/wp/v2/pages?_embed=wp:featuredmedia&_fields=_links.wp:featuredmedia,_embedded
```

Unfortunately I can't manage to make another step of filter for `wp:featuredmedia` so that the response will only return for example its `id` or `source_url` to help minimize the size and make it faster.